# What is this called?

Tags: word-choice

[image: water bottle]
What is the strap on the bottle that says "water" called? Is it called a *banner* or a *strap*?

Comment: We would call it a *label*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would call that a [label](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/label):

> a piece of paper, cloth, or similar material that is attached to something to identify or describe it
>   <sub>source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/label</sub>

Comment: More specifically, if the label was made from shrunken plastic, it would be a _shrink-wrapped label_, and if it was glued on, it would be an _adhesive label_. Depending on the industry, some people put a [lot of thought into this](http://www.nzdl.org/gsdlmod?e=d-00000-00---off-0fnl2.2--00-0----0-10-0---0---0direct-10---4-------0-1l--11-en-50---20-about---00-0-1-00-0--4----0-0-11-10-0utfZz-8-00&a=d&cl=CL1.1&d=HASH014293f8d0af78c65ebf0c2a.7.2).